# Discord bot started without error, but commands do not work

Tags: python, discord.py

I do not speak English, so I apologize for using some translators.

When I debugged Python, no errors were displayed.
I have all @bot.command()
doesn't work
When you create a chat on Discord
@client.event do works
this is part of code

We will send you the full code if necessary

````
import random
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio, discord, time 


permissions = 397287782400

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

intents=discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} 가 성공적으로 똥')
    game = discord.Game('배교닐응디만지기')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I have logged in as {0.user}\n".format(bot))

@bot.command()
async def 안녕(ctx):
    await ctx.send("안녕")


@bot.command()
async def 이호똥(ctx):
    result, _color, bot1, bot2, user1, user2, a, b = dice()

    embed = discord.Embed(title = "이호똥 게임 결과", description = None, color = _color)
    embed.add_field(name = "이호가 싼 똥 " + bot1 + "+" + bot2, value = ":: " + a, inline = False)
    embed.add_field(name = ctx.author.name+"의 똥 " + user1 + "+" + user2, value = ":poop: " + b, inline = False)
    embed.set_footer(text="결과: " + result)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: You can not use `discord.Client` and `commands.Bot` together.

Answer (score -1):

You use both `commands.Bot()` and `discord.Client()`. My suggestion is to use one of them, for example:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

Another suggestion - try to name function in english and then provide the name of the command in `name` property as shown in the example below:

```py
@bot.command(name='list')
async def _list(ctx, arg):
    pass
```

Here is a link to the documentation:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html

Comment: I did not understand the code at the first time. Please, review the answer once again and leave the feedback ;)